# Is there a way to hide autocomplete arrays from HTML source?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a JQuery autocomplete function going, fed by a json_encoded PHP array. Everything is functioning, but when I right click on the site to view the page source, I can see the entire array. What is this array contained sensitive information? Is there a better way to organize this code, making it more private with the same level of functionality?

On the main PHP/HTML page:

```
<?php include 'autocomplete.php'; ?>
```

which includes:

```
    <?php

// connect to db

    //fetch first and last name
    $sql="SELECT first, last FROM names";
    $result = mysqli_query($web_dbi, $sql) or die("Error " . mysqli_error($web_dbi));
    while ($f=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
       $names[] = array(
       'label' => $f['first'] . " " . $f['last'];
        );
    }

    echo json_encode($names);

?>
```

back on the main PHP/HTML page I have some JQuery:

```
    ... (JQuery CDNs)
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            $( "#inputfield" ).autocomplete({
            source: "autocomplete.php",
            minLength: 1,
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                log( ui.item ?
                "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id :
                "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

The main issue is that in the source of the HTML page, this is visible:

```
$(function() {
        var autocompletevalues = ["name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name","name"];
        $( "#inputfield" ).autocomplete({
            dataType: "json",
            source: availableTags
        });
    });
```

Comment: autocomplete values are dynamically fetched by ajax, you dont have to store it in a variable.

Comment: Yes I did. Your HTML page source should not show autocomplete values this way if implemented properly.

Comment: so you recommend I implement autocomplete with ajax instead?

Comment: check my answer. `search.php` has to fetch the values dynamically

Answer (score 0):

It has to be like this:

```
$( "#birds" ).autocomplete({
            source: "search.php",
            minLength: 2,
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                log( ui.item ?
                    "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id :
                    "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );
            }
        });
```

Ref: [JQuery Autocomplete](http://view-source:https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/autocomplete/remote.html)

`search.php` has to ftech `json` values which can then be displayed as a part of autocomplete.

Refer to this Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/handtrix/32Bck/

Update 1:

```
while($product_search->fetch())
        {
            $data[] = array(
                'label' => trim($product_code) 
            );
        }

        echo json_encode($data);
```

JS Code:

```
$("#inputfield").autocomplete({ 
        source:'search.php', 
        minLength:4
    });
```

Comment: It's not completing ... when I inspect element it looks like it's getting caught up on this error:

Comment: xhr.send( ( s.hasContent && s.data ) || null );

Comment: in the search.php file, is "echo json_encode($names);" correct?

Comment: Yes in the form of key value pair.

Comment: I don't have a suggest url ... unless is the search.php file the suggest url?

Comment: I did not understand. Sorry.

Comment: do you know if this is correct syntax in PHP: $names[] = $f['first'] . " " . $f['last'];

Comment: are these key value pairs?

Comment: tested ... getting same error ... I updated my PHP code to reflect the code I'm testing ... is my syntax correct?

Comment: @faalbane U there? Check my js as well

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Please paste it over here.

Comment: no results are loading ... when I inspect the element, it looks like in one of the jquery files it's getting caught up here:

Comment: // Do send the request
// This may raise an exception which is actually
// handled in jQuery.ajax (so no try/catch here)
xhr.send( ( s.hasContent && s.data ) || null );

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104464/discussion-between-fakhruddin-ujjainwala-and-faalbane).